# Multiple TinyMCE editors in dynamically generated textareas

Tags: custom-post-types, tinymce

I have text-areas dynamically populated in the admin section of my custom post type.

```
             <div class="media_div">
                <span>Media</span>
                <input type="text"
                    class="meta_media"
                    name="media_desc[]"
                    value=""
                />
            </div>
```

I then loop through the $_POSTS when saving the meta values, hence using `[]` in the name. The codex says only `lowercase` and `_` can be passed to [wp-editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor).

How can I use wp-editor for these dynamically generated text areas?

```
wp_editor($ID, 'media_desc[]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `wp_editor` is the value that the "id" attribute of the textarea element will have, and that is probably why there are such restrictions on it. By default it is also used for the "name" attribute but you can set it explicitly by using the `$settings` parameter to `wp_editor`

`wp_editor($ID, 'media_desc_n',array('textarea_name' => 'media_desc[n]'));`

Comment: Where does this code go? Before or after the text area code? I seem to be generating the MCE editors with correct ids and names but they are not replacing the text-areas, just showing above them...

Comment: @myol `wp_editor` generates the testarea by itself, you don't need to add an explicit one.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. However, my `textarea` was output in sequence using `$out .=` so now the TinyMCE editor is out of the flow. I tried `$out .= wp_editor(...`

Comment: you can use `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean` to get the output of wp_editor into a string

Comment: I've read the PHP manual after wrapping the `$out .= wp_editor...` it seems to hide the output? Would you mind further clarifying?

Comment: not exactly the same, but the accepted answer is an example how you can convert an output into a string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144222/how-to-get-include-contents-as-a-string

Comment: Works a treat! Excellent, thanks for your patience